# Nazars in Terraria

Tags: terraria

I've been trying to get the "Ankh Charm" in Terraria, which as few people know, can make the player who has it equipped immune to most debuffs. There's only one problem, and that's the Nazar. The Nazar (when equipped) makes the player immune to the "Cursed" debuff, and that's the only thing I need to create the Ankh Charm. You can obtain it by killing a rare mob that spawns in the underground hallow, and the mob has a 1/100 (1%) chance of dropping it. I haven't come across a SINGLE one of these, and I'm just wondering if there's any special way to "lure" them towards me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While possible to obtain in hardmode underground caverns, it is actually much easier to obtain Nazar in a pre-Plantera dungeon. [Cursed Skulls](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Cursed_Skull) have a much higher spawn rate than other nazar-carrying enemies, allowing a little easier time to farm for them.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I just realized I fought Plantera 23 times with my friend JUST so I could gget the Nazar and Armor Polish =/